# Как сделать, чтоб переменная "с'' вводилась и была видна всем блокам?

Tags: c#

```
while (true) {
    double c, t;
    Console.WriteLine("n1-Ввод данныхn2-Выбор способа расчетаn0-Выход ");
    switch (int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())) {

    case 1:
        Console.Write("Введите емкость:");
        string buf = Console.ReadLine();
        double c = Convert.ToDouble(buf);
        break;
    case 2:
        while (true) {
            Console.WriteLine("n1-Цикл Forn2-Цикл do...whilenЦикл While n0-Выход ");
            switch (int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())) {
            case 1:
                for (int r = 100; r <= 1000; r = r + 100) {
                    t = r * c;
                    Console.WriteLine("t={0}", t);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                {
                    int r = 100;
                    do {
                        t = r * c;
                        r = r + 100;
                        Console.WriteLine("t=" + t);
                    }
                    while (r <= 1000);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                {
                    int r = 100;
                    while (r <= 1000) {

                        t = r * c;
                        r = r + 100;
                        Console.WriteLine("t={0}", t);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 0:
                return;
            default:
                Console.Write("Вы ввели неверную команду!!!");
                break;

            }
        }
        break;
    case 0:
        return;
        break;
    default:
        Console.Write("Вы ввели неверную команду!!!");
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так)

```
while (true) { 
      double c, t; 
      Console.WriteLine("n1-Ввод данныхn2-Выбор способа расчетаn0-Выход "); 
  switch (int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())) {

    case 1:
        Console.Write("Введите емкость:");
        string buf = Console.ReadLine();
        c = Convert.ToDouble(buf);//здесь изменено!!!
        break;
    case 2:
        while (true) {
            Console.WriteLine("n1-Цикл Forn2-Цикл do...whilenЦикл While n0-Выход ");
            switch (int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())) {
            case 1:
                for (int r = 100; r <= 1000; r = r + 100) {
                    t = r * c;
                    Console.WriteLine("t={0}", t);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                {
                    int r = 100;
                    do {
                        t = r * c;
                        r = r + 100;
                        Console.WriteLine("t=" + t);
                    }
                    while (r <= 1000);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                {
                    int r = 100;
                    while (r <= 1000) {

                        t = r * c;
                        r = r + 100;
                        Console.WriteLine("t={0}", t);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 0:
                return;
            default:
                Console.Write("Вы ввели неверную команду!!!");
                break;

            }
        }
        break;
    case 0:
        return;
        break;
    default:
        Console.Write("Вы ввели неверную команду!!!");
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Так переменная "с" будет видна для текущего метода класса.
А если надо для всей программы тогда определи как поле public у этого класса

Comment: все понятно но  фишка еще в том что пишет  "переменной С не присвоено значение "

Comment: спасибо я понял  решение этой задачи! благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы переменная была доступна во всех блоках, она должна быть объявлена вне этих блоков. То есть

```
double c;
while (true) {
    // TODO:
    c = 0;
}
```

При этом переменная не должна переопределяться внутри вложенных блоков, то есть не должно быть

```
{
    double c = 0;
}
```

Должно быть

```
{
    c = 0;
}
```

Comment: Я вас понял, но код все равно не работает!

Comment: Обновил ответ.